# Filter on array value in ArangoDB

Tags: arangodb

I have a document like this:

```
{   "baths": 2,   "beds": 3,   "id": "3225C",   "addrs": [
    {
      "line2": "",
      "line3": "",
      "state": "OH",
      "zip": "67845",
      "line1": "3225 ABC AVE",
      "city": "CLEVELAND"
    },
    {
      "line2": "",
      "line3": "",
      "state": "FL",
      "zip": "32818",
      "line1": "2438 DEF AVE",
      "city": "ORLANDO"
    }   ],   "homeAddress": {
    "line2": "",
    "line3": "",
    "state": "FL",
    "zip": "32818",
    "line1": "1234 CHICOTA AVE",
    "city": "ORLANDO"   },   "rentingAddresses": {
    "ownsObjects": true,
    "count": 0,
    "arrayManager": {},
    "items": []   },   "mailAddress": [
    "4561 RAYCO AVE",
    "",
    "",
    "ORLANDO",
    "FL",
    "32818"   ] }
```

I'm trying to find which clients have an `addrs` where the state is in "OH". My aql query is:

```
for client in clients.addrs
filter client.state == "OH"
return client
```

But I keep getting `[1563] list expected`. Is there some other way to work with arrays?

Answer (score 14):

you can do this:

```
FOR client IN clients
   FILTER 'OH' IN client.addrs[*].state
   RETURN client
```

this should return all clients which have at least one element in the
"addrs" attribute with "state" == "OH"

Answer (score 1):

first you have to select a doc in that collection by using filter like this:

```
FOR doc IN clients
 FILTER doc.id == "3225C"
   FOR d IN doc.addrs
    FILTER d.state == "OH"
   RETURN d
```

this will return the `addrs` object in which state == "OH". if you want to get complete doc, just replace `RETURN d` with `RETURN doc` .

Comment: I request you to please add some more context around your answer. Code-only or link-only answers are difficult to understand. It will help the asker and future readers both if you can add more information in your post.

Comment: Thank you! for your suggestion.